# Access <a> elements on Angular site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, powershell

I am looking to fill an array with `<a>` elements on an AngularJS site. Here is my array code:

```
$ProgramGuides = $ProgramGuidesPage.ParsedHtml.getElementById("content") | foreach {
                    $_.getElementsByTagName("ul").item(0) | foreach {
                        $_.getElementsByTagName("li") | foreach {
                            $_.getElementsByTagName("a")
                        }

              }
}
```

`$ProgramGuides` only returns 1 `<a>` element meanwhile there are 10+ `<a>` elements on the page. I can only imagine this has something to do with Angular and ng-repeat on the elements. Any ideas how I can get all the `<a>` elements into my array?

Here is the HTML of the Angular page:

Update: Found the XML document with the app data!!
[image]

How can I grab the href values inside this XML content?

This is how I am grabbing the Content:

```
$XMLPage = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ("https://sellerweb.amerihome.com/api/ResourcesFiles?path=ProgramGuides") -WebSession $Amerihome

$XMLPage.Content
```

Output of Get-Member on $XMLPage
[image: output of Get-Member]

Comment: Are you parsing the source code? In which case there will only be the one `<a>` element in the `ng-repeat` template. You need to get hold of the angular-compiled html

Comment: Yes I believe I am parsing the source code. How can I get hold of the angular compiled html?

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but where is the AngularJS app getting the data? Is that something (JSON or XML) you can reach with your PowerShell script? That would be much more straightforward...

Comment: Wish I could answer that, but im not sure. I dug into the 'Sources' tab in the chrome inspector but can't find anywhere that shows where the data comes from

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't something available online..?

Comment: It is, but login credentials are required, and unfortunately i'm not at liberty to provide those online :/

Comment: No problem, I get that. Any idea where resourcesFilesInfo is coming from?

Comment: Believe I found where the data is coming from. Captured the requests in Fiddler and saw a request with the url: "https://sellerweb.amerihome.com/api/ResourcesFiles?path=ProgramGuides" which leads me to the xml page with all the data and links. On to something...

Comment: Any idea how I can extract the href values from this XML doc?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see from that screenshot, but this is the general idea:

```
$url = "https://sellerweb.amerihome.com/..."
$result = Invoke-WebRequest $url
$xml = [xml]$result.Content
```

Once you have that XML object defined you should be able to reference the object structure:

```
$xml[0].Name
$xml[0].Link
```

Comment: I've been trying to select the attributes with Select-XML but with no luck. I added a screenshot of the XML code in my original post. I got too excited when I found the XML data and figured it would be easy to extract the link data. Boy was I wrong

Comment: Failing on `$xml = [xml]$result.Content`. "Cannot convert value to type System.Xml.XmlDocument. Error: The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type." ....could it be my XML content is in wrong format?

Comment: Likely. Does $result.Content give you something that looks like XML?

Comment: Looks like XML to me. $result.Content is the same data as in my prior screenshot. Is that proper XML format, in your eyes?

Comment: No, what you're trying to get to is just the XML content.

Comment: So the data is not even XML? Is there any way for me to work with this content to get the Link values?

Comment: It could very well be XML, but you're not really providing any information on how you got to the screenshot provided above. Based on the Mode and LastWriteTime fields I'm assuming you saved the contents locally, rather than using the code I provided above, but you aren't being terribly clear on that point.

Comment: added the code I use to get the screenshot data, in my OP. I also used your code but that gave me an error:  "Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the 
valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type." That error message correlates to this line: `$XML = [xml]$result.Content`

Comment: What do you get if you use Get-Member on $XMLPage?

Comment: Added screenshot to OP. Specifically, I called `Get-Member -InputObject $XMLPage`

Comment: And you're certain $XMLPage.Content returned the screenshot? It should be returning a string, not an Object.