# Get hold of angular compiled html

Tags: angularjs, powershell, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using PowerShell is it possible to access the angular compiled html? My script seems to be parsing the source code which does not have all the elements I need (likely due to ng-repeat hiding the repeated elements). Someone recommended I parse the angular-compiled html which will have all the elements. Any know how to do this, if at all possible?

Comment: "My script seems to... " - what script?

Comment: My PowerShell script. It logs into a site and navigates to a section of the site with a bunch of links to PDFs that I wish to download. But the page is coded with AngularJS and I am unable to make reference to the links.

Comment: You're much more likely to get some help if you can share some example code, both the PowerShell and AngularJS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924687/access-a-elements-on-angular-site?noredirect=1#comment61410656_36924687