# How to reference angular-compiled html?

Tags: angularjs, powershell, dom

Is there a way to retrieve the html document of an angularjs web page so that I can reference all the elements on the page? For example, this site has 10 pdfs but when I Chrome-inspect I see that it uses ng-repeat and there is only 1 `<li>` which is referencing all 11 PDFs with ng-repeat. Any way to get a reference to all the PDFs? Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the reference to the PDFs? The model of `ng-repeat` will probably contain all references but that's just a guess with-out seeing any code. Can you please explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want the hrefs so I can download them with Invoke-WebRequest

Comment: my prior post - contains code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924687/access-a-elements-on-angular-site?noredirect=1#comment61410656_36924687